# I want a function to return a certain value, else return false

Tags: function, unity-game-engine, return, return-type

In short, I notice that a lot of predefined functions in Unity (A simple game development platform I use) will either return a value (Such as a coordinate), or will return false if certain conditions are met. I attempted to do this myself, however the compiler is always looking for a transform as a return type, and will not allow me to return a boolean (because the function is declared to return a transform).

```
    Transform SelectObject() {
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, unitLayer))
        return hit.transform;
    else
        return false;
}
```

How do I return a certain data type, but also have my function return boolean (false) when the function 'fails' its task?

Comment: Even pre-defined functions should be documented somewhere. Maybe you want to look out for some examples of such behavior. I am not into Unity, but what you are describing here sounds rather weird. Are you sure that there aren't some **implicit** conversions that translate something like "null" return into false under the covers?!

Comment: @GhostCat The answer was right there in my code the whole time. I did not understand the basic concept of the "out" keyword. Certain predefined functions such as "Physics.Raycast()" will return true or false depending on whether or not certain conditions were met, but those functions will also pass along extra information through another variable with the "out" keyword. Effectively returning a boolean AND some extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Unity for a while, but I think you just need to do this:

```
Transform SelectObject() {
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, unitLayer))
        return hit.transform;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Unity have an utility that converts objects that derive from `UnityEngine.Object` to boolean: false if the object is null, true in other cases.
This is a weird thing, but it actually worked for me.

I think you can implicitly convert Transform objects to boolean like this:

```
bool b = SelectObject();
```